# Android webview stopped to play html5 videos

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

A few days ago I started to receive support requests from my users that thay can not view videos anymore in the Android webview app despite the fact that so far everything has worked well.

I tested it on my phone and everything was working fine but today the same thing is happening on my phone.

When video starts playing, immediately appears error page "error.html" that should appear when there is no Internet connection.

```
private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // get_location();
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        findViewById(es.cchat.cchat.R.id.msw_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Went Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        aswm_view("file:///android_res/raw/error.html", false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Went Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        aswm_view("file:///android_res/raw/error.html", false);
    }

    //Overriding webview URLs
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return url_actions(view, url);
    }

    //Overriding webview URLs for API 23+ [suggested by github.com/JakePou]
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return url_actions(view, request.getUrl().toString());
    }
}
```

I had this:

```
<video class="video" id="bVideo" autoplay controls controlsList="nodownload">
<source src="<?php echo $vfile;?>" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I tried to use [Video.js](https://videojs.com/) but there is the same problem:

```
<video id="my-player" autoplay="true" class="video-js imgw2" controls preload="none" poster="<?php echo $tfile;?>"

  <source src="<?php echo $vfile;?>" type="video/mp4"></source>
  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript
  </p>
</video>
```

Any ideas?